# Adding a parameter to the fields of a django form which is accessible from the templates

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a Django form which is passed to the templates through the view. In the form's `__init__`  I' m trying to add a parameter to each field, which is accessible from code, but not from the template.

forms.py

```
class GenForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)  
        super(GenForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].dest = 'test_value'
            help_text = self.fields[field].help_text
```

template

```
{% for field in form %}
    {{ field.help_text }} || {{ field.dest }}
{% endfor %}
```

views.py

```
ret_dic['form'] = GenForm(request = request)
return render(request, 'template_file', ret_dic)
```

My goal would be to reach the dest value for the fields from the template, but it's not displayed at all. What is strange / interesting, is that I can reach the dest value from code:

ipython

```
gen = GenForm()
gen.fields['name'].dest
#results: test_value
```

My questions are:

1. how could I reach the dest variable from the template?
2. why is the dest value reachable from code, but not from template?

The help_text I can reach from the code and also from the template. Should I somehow register it maybe?

Python: 3.4
Django: 1.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field that you access in the template is actually an instance of BoundField. You can access the actual underlying field via the `.field` attribute. So this would work:

```
{{ field.help_text }} || {{ field.field.dest }}
```

Comment: So simply? I missed this completely... . Thanks.